# Controlling indent and vertical space at top of a tcolorbox

Tags: spacing, tcolorbox

I would like to set up a `tcolorbox` where the first paragraph is not indented, but subsequent paragraphs are indented.

I can accomplish this by passing an option like this to the box:

```
before upper=\setlength{\parindent}{1em}\noindent
```

The problem with this is that the `\noindent` causes TeX to enter horizontal mode. So if I start the box with something that should be in vertical mode (e.g., `\section`), extra vertical is inserted.

Is there a way I can automatically get the output I want without having to create two different kinds of boxes?

## MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\tcbset{mybox/.style={colback=white, colframe=blue, left=2mm, right=2mm,
  fonttitle=\bfseries}, fontupper=\small,
  before upper=\setlength{\parindent}{1em}\noindent}

\newtcolorbox{mybox}[1][]{mybox,#1}

\begin{document}

\begin{mybox}
  The first paragraph should not have an indent.

  Subsequent paragraphs should be indented.
\end{mybox}

\begin{mybox}
  \section{Should not have gap above this heading}
\end{mybox}

\begin{mybox}[before upper=\setlength{\parindent}{1em}]
  \section{Previous box should look like this}
\end{mybox}

\end{document}
```

[image: MWE output]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a simplified version of `\@afterheading`:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\tcbset{mybox/.style={colback=white, colframe=blue, left=2mm, right=2mm,
  fonttitle=\bfseries}, fontupper=\small,
  before upper=\setlength{\parindent}{1em}\everypar{{\setbox0\lastbox}\everypar{}},
}

\newtcolorbox{mybox}[1][]{mybox,#1}

\begin{document}

\begin{mybox}
  The first paragraph should not have an indent.

  Subsequent paragraphs should be indented.
\end{mybox}

\begin{mybox}
  \section{Should not have gap above this heading}
\end{mybox}

\begin{mybox}[before upper=\setlength{\parindent}{1em}]
  \section{Previous box should look like this}
\end{mybox}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The tokens in `\everypar` are inserted after the paragraph has started, so just after the indentation box; with `{\setbox0\lastbox}` the indentation box is removed and put in box 0, which is then reset to what it was because the assignment happens in a group. Then `\everypar` is reset to empty.

Comment: That's close! But it has an odd side effect. The vertical space before a `center` environment disappears. e.g., add `\begin{center}Text\end{center}` to the end of the first box.

Comment: @DavidPurton What would be the reason for keeping that space?

Comment: A `center` environment usually has space above and below right? With your code the space is still inserted below the `center` environment, but removed from above. This seems odd to me :)

Comment: @DavidPurton Try `\begin{center}Text\end{center}` at the top of a `minipage`.

Comment: Yeah, but when not at top of a `minipage` There is still space above. I mean this output is weird (with your `\everypar` code):`\begin{mybox}Text\begin{center}Text\end{center}Text\end{mybox}`

Comment: Without the `\everypar{…}` it behaves as I would expect.

Comment: Compare also `\begin{mybox}Text\begin{itemize}\item Text\end{itemize}Text\begin{center}Text\end{center}Text\end{mybox}` Where the `itemize` spacing is wrong, but the `center` spacing is right.

Comment: @DavidPurton I'm not sure what you mean. If I set `top=0pt` in the definition of `mybox`, I get the same space with `center`, `itemize` or simple text; more precisely, the first baseline is at the same position in all cases.

Comment: Sorry, I must not be clear! I have asked a followup question at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/503357/followup-controlling-indent-and-vertical-space-at-top-of-a-tcolorbox