# Followup: Controlling indent and vertical space at top of a tcolorbox

Tags: spacing, tcolorbox

This is a followup question to [Controlling indent and vertical space at top of a tcolorbox](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/503220/controlling-indent-and-vertical-space-at-top-of-a-tcolorbox).

@egreg provided a nice solution to the original problem, but there is one side effect when certain environments (probably anything based on a `trivlist`) appear in the `tcolorbox`. The spacing above the first environment is missing.

How can I adjust @egreg's answer so that these environments are spaced correctly?

## MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\tcbset{mybox/.style={colback=white, colframe=blue, left=2mm, right=2mm,
  fonttitle=\bfseries}, fontupper=\small,
  before upper=\setlength{\parindent}{1em}\everypar{{\setbox0\lastbox}\everypar{}},
}

\newtcolorbox{mybox}[1][]{mybox,#1}

\begin{document}
\begin{mybox}
  This line should not be indented.

  This line should be indented.

  \begin{center}
    This line should be centred. The spacing above is wrong.
  \end{center}

  This line should be indented.

  \begin{center}
    This line should be centred. The spacing above is right.
  \end{center}

  This line should be indented.
\end{mybox}

\begin{mybox}
  \section{Should not have gap above this heading}
\end{mybox}
\end{document}
```

[image: MWE output]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The missing vertical space in the inner `center` environment is because `\@item` uses `\addvspace\@topsep` to insert the space you want to have when leaving a blank line before `\begin{center}`, and `\addvspace` doesn't add this space when in vertical mode and `\if@minipage` is true—which is the case inside your `mybox`. So, in order to have this space inserted, you can set `\@minipagefalse` in the `before upper` option of your `tcolorbox`.

The vertical gap between the two boxes is essentially due to the default for `/tcb/noparskip` (see documentation of `/tcb/autoparskip` in the `tcolorbox` manual). If you set `before=\par\noindent`, you remove the added `\smallskip`:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\makeatletter

\tcbset{mybox/.style={colback=white, colframe=blue, left=2mm, right=2mm,
  fonttitle=\bfseries}, fontupper=\small,
  before upper={\setlength{\parindent}{1em}%
                \everypar{{\setbox0\lastbox}\@minipagefalse\everypar{}}},
  before=\par\noindent, after=\par
}

\makeatother

\newtcolorbox{mybox}[1][]{mybox,#1}

\begin{document}
\begin{mybox}
  This line should not be indented.

  This line should be indented.

  \begin{center}
    This line should be centered. The spacing above is correct.
  \end{center}

  This line should be indented.

  \begin{center}
    This line should be centered. The spacing above is right.
  \end{center}

  This line should be indented.
\end{mybox}

\begin{mybox}
  \section{Should not have gap above this heading}
\end{mybox}
\end{document}
```

[image: Screenshot]

If you really want to get rid of *all the gap*, suppress all vertical glue between the two boxes of interest here that are appended to the main vertical list. You can do this using `\nointerlineskip`, which is correctly used in vertical mode because of the `after=\par` we set:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\makeatletter

\tcbset{mybox/.style={colback=white, colframe=blue, left=2mm, right=2mm,
  fonttitle=\bfseries}, fontupper=\small,
  before upper={\setlength{\parindent}{1em}%
                \everypar{{\setbox0\lastbox}\@minipagefalse\everypar{}}},
  before=\par\noindent, after=\par
}

\makeatother

\newtcolorbox{mybox}[1][]{mybox,#1}

\begin{document}
\begin{mybox}
  This line should not be indented.

  This line should be indented.

  \begin{center}
    This line should be centered. The spacing above is correct.
  \end{center}

  This line should be indented.

  \begin{center}
    This line should be centered. The spacing above is right.
  \end{center}

  This line should be indented.
\end{mybox}
\nointerlineskip
\begin{mybox}
  \section{Should not have gap above this heading}
\end{mybox}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note: I set the `\@minipagefalse` inside the temporary `\everypar` in order not to have extra vertical space inside the box if it starts with a `center` environment. But if you set it directly at the beginning of `before upper`, like this:

```latex
\tcbset{mybox/.style={colback=white, colframe=blue, left=2mm, right=2mm,
  fonttitle=\bfseries}, fontupper=\small,
  before upper={\@minipagefalse\setlength{\parindent}{1em}%
                \everypar{{\setbox0\lastbox}\everypar{}}},
  before=\par\noindent, after=\par
}
```

and start your box with a `center` environment:

```latex
\begin{mybox}
  \begin{center}
    This line should be centered. The spacing above is correct.
  \end{center}

  This line should be indented.

  \begin{center}
    This line should be centered. The spacing above is correct.
  \end{center}
...
\end{mybox}
```

you'll get the extra space at the top of your box, like this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! The space between the boxes is fine. The heading was related to the previous question. I finally see what was causing me grief! I had `before upper=\setlength{\parindent}{1em}` in my box settings and this doesn't cause the spacing difference. I see now that it does occur in the default `tcolorbox` :/ My bad.

Comment: Glad to see this solves your issue. I added a precision regarding inside spacing at the top of the box.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Putting `\@minipagefalse` inside `\everypar{}` does what I want. (I think).

Comment: This literally saved my life after updating tcolorbox and seeing the vertical space. I'm not sure why it wasn't happening before, but the `\@minipagefalse` did the trick!