# Mdframed two color on background and text as watermark

Tags: tikz-pgf, xetex, mdframed

I will expand the old question a little. I need something like this.
There are no graphs in the background, everything is text.
I did not find a way to put the text on the background, as soon as I did not predefine it.

```
\mdfdefinestyle{bible}{
  backgroundcolor=black!15,
  linecolor=black!25,
  leftmargin=4mm,
  rightmargin=0,
  innerrightmargin=2mm,
  innerleftmargin=20mm,
  roundcorner=8pt,
   apptotikzsetting={%
     \tikzset{mdfbackground/.style={},}
   },
  singleextra={%
    \scoped[on background layer]{\node [xshift=.2*\mdfboundingboxwidth, yshift=.7*\mdfboundingboxheight, opacity=0.4] 
    {"};
    }
  },
}
```

But this completely removes the background fill, but I need a light gray color.
[image]

Comment: "I will expand the old question a little." *Which* old question? Please provide us with an MWE that starts with `\documentclass` and ends with `\end{document}`. `M` stands for minimal, and `W` for working.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat, just a guess, but I wonder if the OP means *original* question, i.e., the question in the title. Could be a victim of Google translate :).

Answer (score 4):

I do this kind of thing a lot, but I use `tcolorbox`. This is my set up for Bible quotes, but with the style slightly adjusted to match your picture.

The main work (and all you really need) is done by the `\newtcolorbox{greyquote}` macro. It's mostly self explanatory, except for the `before upper` setting, which I use to provide more consistent spacing in the box, otherwise it can go wrong in certain situations (see my questions [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503357/87678) and [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503220/87678)).

The rest is just convenience macros to set and format the Bible quotes like I want them.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[breakable,skins]{tcolorbox}

\makeatletter
\newtcolorbox{greyquote}[1][]{
  enhanced jigsaw,
  colframe=black!60, colback=black!15, arc=8pt, 
  top=2mm, right=2mm, bottom=2mm, left=12mm,
  before upper=\setlength{\parindent}{1em}\everypar{{\setbox0\lastbox}\@minipagefalse\everypar{}},
  underlay={
    \path[fill=black!25,draw=none] (interior.south west) --
      ([xshift=10mm]interior.south west) --
      ([xshift=10mm]interior.north west) [rounded corners=8pt] --
      (interior.north west) -- cycle;
    \node [anchor=north, yshift=-2mm] at ([xshift=5mm]interior.north west)
      {\sffamily\Huge\bfseries ``};
  },
  #1}
\makeatother

\newcommand*{\biblequotefont}{\sffamily}
\newcommand*{\bibleversion}{NIVUK}

\newcommand{\formatbibleversion}{%
  \def\emptybibleversion{}%
  \ifx\emptybibleversion\bibleversion
  \else
    \space(\bibleversion)%
  \fi}

\newcommand{\formatbibleref}[1]{%
  \textbf{#1\formatbibleversion}}

\newenvironment{biblequote}[1][]%
  {%
    \par
    \parindent 1.3em
    \biblequotefont
    \def\biblequoteref{#1}%
    \def\emptybiblequoteref{}%
    \ifx\emptybiblequoteref\biblequoteref%
      \def\biblequoteref{}%
    \else
      \def\biblequoteref{%
        {\unskip\nobreak\hfil\penalty50\hskip2em\hbox{}\nobreak
        \hfil\formatbibleref{#1}\parfillskip=0pt \finalhyphendemerits=0
            \par}}%
    \fi
    \noindent\ignorespaces
  }{%
    \biblequoteref
  }

\newenvironment{greybiblequote}[1][]{%
  \begin{greyquote}
    \begin{biblequote}[#1]
}{%
    \end{biblequote}
  \end{greyquote}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{greybiblequote}[John 1:1--8]
  In the beginning was the Word, and the Word was with God, and the Word was
  God. He was with God in the beginning. Through him all things were made;
  without him nothing was made that has been made. In him was life, and that
  life was the light of all mankind. The light shines in the darkness, and the
  darkness has not overcome it.

  There was a man sent from God whose name was John. He came as a witness to
  testify concerning that light, so that through him all might believe. He
  himself was not the light; he came only as a witness to the light.
\end{greybiblequote}
\end{document}
```

[image: Output]

Answer (score 0):

[image]Here is my code with mdframed

```
\documentclass[a4paper, openright, 11pt]{extreport}
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage[left=20mm,right=10mm,top=17mm,bottom=20mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[main=russian,english]{babel}    %% загружает пакет многоязыковой вёрстки
                   %% подготавливает загрузку шрифтов Open Type, True Type и др.
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{titlesec,titletoc}
\usepackage{paralist}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\usepackage{enumitem}
%\usepackage{balance}
\usepackage{metalogo}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage[final]{microtype}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
%\usepackage{xifthen}
%\usepackage[colorlinks=true,linkcolor=black]{hyperref}


% -------------- Настраваем шрифты -----------------------------

\usepackage{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Scale=MatchUppercase}
\usepackage{setspace}
%\setmainfont{Alfios} % Основной текстовый шрифт
%\setmainfont{EB Garamond 12 Regular} % Основной шрифт текста

\setmainfont{Alegreya}
%\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Schola}
\onehalfspacing

\setsansfont [UprightFont = *]{Fregat}  % Шрифт замечаний
\newfontfamily{\ivry}{Linux Biolinum O}  % Для слов на иврите
\newfontfamily{\bibquf}[StylisticSet=1]{Montserrat}[
  FontFace={ms}{n}{Font=* Medium},
  FontFace={ms}{it}{Font=* Medium Italic}
]

\newfontfamily{\fyanone}{Fregat}
%\newfontfamily{\chn}{Cocogoose Pro Block Gradient}  % Шрифт для оглавления
\newfontfamily{\chn}{Ossem Rust}  % Шрифт для оглавления
%\newfontfamily{\chn}{Fregat}  % Шрифт для оглавления
\newcommand*{\bibqufont}[1]{\bibquf\scriptsize{#1}}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\bqseries}{\fontseries{ms}\selectfont}
%\DeclareTextFontCommand{\textsb}{\bfseries}

% --------------- Формат для оглавлений ------------------------
\titleformat
    {\chapter} % command
    [display]  % shape
    {\Huge\bfseries} % format
    {
    \raggedleft
    {
        \fyanone\bfseries\fontsize{48pt}{48pt}\selectfont Часть
            \chn\fontsize{64pt}{20pt}\selectfont\thechapter}
    } % label
    {-6pt} % sep
    {
        \titlerule[2.5pt]
        \vspace{1.2pt}
        \titlerule[1.2pt]
    } % before-code

\titleformat{\section}[display]
    {\Large\sffamily}
    {}{}{\uppercase}
  [
    \vspace{-12pt}%
    \rule{36mm}{0.5pt}
    \vspace{4pt}
  ] %

\titleformat{\subsection}[wrap]
{\bfseries\sffamily}
{}{}{}[]

\titlespacing{\subsection}
{8pc}{1.5ex}{1pc}


%------------------- Содержание ---------------------------
\titlecontents{chapter}
[2.5em]
{\addvspace{20pt}\filcenter}
{\Large\MakeUppercase{часть\ \thecontentslabel}\ \sffamily\itshape\bfseries\Large}
{\sffamily\itshape\bfseries\Large}
{}
[\rule{\textwidth}{1pt}\hspace*{8pt}]

\titlecontents{section}
[0pt]
{\addvspace{1pt}}
{}
{\normalsize\sffamily\uppercase}
{\titlerule*[4pt]{.}\contentspage}

\titlecontents{subsection}
[25pt]
{\addvspace{1pt}}
{}
{\sffamily\bfseries}
{\titlerule*[4pt]{.}\contentspage}

% ---------------- Счетчики ------------------------
\newcounter{qenum}
\newcounter{q1}
\newlength{\mdffrw}

\newcommand{\qa}{\addtocounter{q1}{1}\arabic{q1})\ }

\newenvironment{quest}{%
 \setcounter{qenum}{0}
 \sffamily
 \vspace{12pt}
 \centerline{\textbf{Вопросы для размышления:}}
 \vspace*{-6pt}
 \centerline{\rule{120pt}{0.5pt}}
 \vspace*{-12pt}
 \small
 \begin{enumerate} \leftskip=0.5em \rightskip=0.5em \parskip-1em \itemsep=1.3em \parsep=0em
 \item[]}
 {\end{enumerate}}


%-------------- Настройка стиля mdframed для цитат-------------------
\mdfdefinestyle{bible}{
  linewidth=0,
  backgroundcolor=white,
  linecolor=black!100,
  leftmargin=4mm,
  rightmargin=0,
  innerrightmargin=0.5em,
  innerleftmargin=36pt,
  innerbottommargin=12pt,
  startinnercode={\baselineskip=10pt},
  apptotikzsetting={%
     \tikzset{mdfbackground/.style={},}
  },
  firstextra={%
    \scoped[on background layer]{
      \node[left] at (30pt,\mdfboundingboxheight-18pt){\bibquf\fontsize{36pt}{36pt}\bfseries\selectfont\color{black!10} “}
    }
  },
  singleextra={%
    \scoped[on background layer]{
      \node[left] at (30pt,\mdfboundingboxheight-18pt){\bibquf\fontsize{36pt}{36pt}\bfseries\selectfont\color{black!10} “};
    }
  },
  extra={%
  \scoped[on background layer]{
      \setlength{\mdffrw}{0.4pt}
      \begin{tikzpicture}
        \fill [black!45,rounded corners=8pt, draw] 
        (0,0) rectangle (\mdfboundingboxwidth,\mdfboundingboxheight);
       \begin{scope}
          \clip (32pt,0) rectangle (\mdfboundingboxwidth,\mdfboundingboxheight);
          \fill [black!20,rounded corners=8pt-\mdffrw, draw] 
          (\mdffrw,\mdffrw) rectangle (\mdfboundingboxwidth-\mdffrw,\mdfboundingboxheight-\mdffrw);
       \end{scope}
       % \node[above left,black!80] at (16pt,16pt) {aas}; %{\fontsize{8}{6}\selectfont\fyanone "};
      \end{tikzpicture};
    }
  },
}


%--------------------------------------------------------------------
%               Create a new command
%               /bquute  цитата из Библии
%--------------------------------------------------------------------
\newcommand{\bquote}[2]{
  \begin{mdframed}[style=bible]{
    \bibqufont{#1}
    \hfil\penalty 200\hskip1em\hbox{}\nobreak\hfill\bqseries\itshape\scriptsize\hbox{#2}
  }
  \end{mdframed}
}


% ---------------- Основная информация книги ----------------------



% ================ Настройка некоторых параметров =================|
\sloppy %------------------------------ Красивое формирование строк|
\parindent=18pt %------------------------------Отступ первой строки|
\setlength{\columnsep}{14pt} %------------Растояние между колонками|
\setlength{\columnseprule}{0.05pt} %----------Линия между колонками|
% -----------------------------------------------------------------|
%\tolerance=600
%\emergencystretch=2pt
\hfuzz=0.9pt
\doublehyphendemerits=9000000
% ---------------- Двухколоночное формирование текста -------------
\twocolumn
\clubpenalty=10000
\widowpenalty=10000
\raggedbottom
\hyphenpenalty=800
\righthyphenmin=2

\makeatletter
\def\qitem{\begingroup\catcode`\^^M=12 \qitem@}
\bgroup\catcode`\^^M=12 %
   \gdef\qitem@#1^^M{\addtocounter{qenum}{1}\item[\textbf{В.\arabic{qenum}:}] #1?\endgroup}%
\egroup
\makeatother

\linespread{0.93}

\ULdepth = 0.2em

%==================================================================
%                                                                 |
%                   BEGIN OF DOCUMENT                             |
%                                                                 |      
%==================================================================

\begin{document}
\author{Igor Yuchimenko}
\title{Test Of XeLaTeX features}


% ================ Main content of book ========================
\chapter {Main chapter}

Отец Аврама — Терах\footnote{В русском синодальном переводе звучит как „Фарра“, но евреи произносят его именно так.} — арамей, происходит из колена Сима, сына Ноя. О нём есть упоминания в текстах Мари (XVIII в. до н.э.) как о главном городе амореев на севере Месопотамии и важном центре пересечения торговых путей. Его достопримечательностью был храм Сина — бога луны. \par
Нам неизвестно о всех переживаниях и сомнениях, но решение было принято: вместе вместе со своей женой Сарой и племянником Лотом уже немолодой человек отправился в путь. Если внимательно взглянуть, Аврам уже вначале явил непослушание Богу „выйти из родства“. В дальнейшем это привело к неприятным моментам в жизни самого Лота: гибели его жены, пленению, греху его дочерей, в результате которого он стал отцом собственных внуков: Моава и Амнона. Да и Авраму создало немало хлопот и переживаний.\par
Трудно сказать о реакции на это Аврама. Легко представить, как он встал и пошёл, тем более уже зная, конец всей истории. Но тогда это было никому пока ещё не ведомо. По факту пришлось действовать вслепую: покинуть родной дом и уйти неизвестно куда. Дальнейшей разворот событий показывал, неоднократность сомнений этого человека, ведь было нелегко. Во-первых, бросить отца сродни отречения от наследства. Во-вторых, путешествие могло закончиться плачевно: пустыня буквально кишела разными племенами. \par
Израильтяне вышли из Египта, фактически, уже поучив свободу, но образ мышления по-прежнему оставался рабским, они мыслили как подневольный и зависимый народ. Чтобы в корне переменить их мышления требовалось время, и Бог знал как действовать. Первая трудность — выбор пути по какому вести этот народ. \bquote {Бог не повёл их через филистимкую землю — это слишком короткий путь. Бог думал: когда сыны Израилевы увидят, им предстоит война, могут передумать и тогда вернутся в Египет.}{Исх. 13:17 НРБО} \par
Это всё, что мы можем узнать о Терахе из Библии. Дальше фокус повествования смещается на его сына Аврама, которому в Харране явился Бог\footnote{Это было первое явления Бога Авраму, о котором сказано в Библии} со словами: \bquote {Оставь отчий дом и родных и иди в землю, которую Я укажу тебе, ибо произведу от тебя многочисленный народ, и ты станешь благословением для всех народов земли. Кто тебя благословит, того Я благословлю, кто тебя проклянет — того Я прокляну.}{Книга Бытия} \par

% =================================================================

\end{document}
```